# Is there a design pattern to follow to avoid updating same record more than once in different methods?

Tags: apex, trigger

Pseudo code to describe the problem I am facing.

**ContractTrigger.trigger**:

```
trigger ContractTrigger on Contract (after update) {

    ContractTriggerHelper helperObj = new ContractTriggerHelper();

    if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
        helperObj.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
    }

}
```

**ContractTriggerHelper.cls**:

```
public class ContractTriggerHelper{

    public void onAfterUpdate(List<Contract> newList, Map<Id,Contract> oldMap){
        Set<Id> accIdSet = new Set<Id>();

        for(Contract contractObj: newList){
            if(contractObj.Status == 'Activated' && 
                oldMap.get(contractObj.Id).Status != contractObj.Status){
                accIdSet.add(contractObj.AccountId);
            }
        }

        AccountUtility.setAccountStatus(accIdSet);
        AccountUtility.setBillCycleDay(accIdSet);
    }

}
```

**AccountUtility.cls**:

```
public class AccountUtility{

    public static void setAccountStatus(Set<Id> accIdSet){
        List<Contract> contractList = [SELECT   Id 
                                        FROM    Contract 
                                        WHERE   AccountId IN: accIdSet];
        List<Account> accListToUpdate = new List<Account>();


        for(Contract contractObj: contractList){
            Boolean accStatus;
            //Assume there is some complex logic 
            //here that can't be handled in Roll-up summary.
            Account accObj = new Account(Id = contractObj.AccountId);
            accObj.Status__c = accStatus;
            accListToUpdate.add(accObj);
        }

        update accListToUpdate;
    }

    public static void setBillCycleDay(Set<Id> accIdSet){
        List<Contract> contractList = [SELECT   Id 
                                        FROM    Contract 
                                        WHERE   AccountId IN: accIdSet];
        List<Account> accListToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for(Contract contractObj: contractList){
            Date dateToUpdate;
            //Assume there is some complex logic 
            //here that can't be handled in Roll-up summary.            
            Account accObj = new Account(Id = contractObj.AccountId);
            accObj.BillCycleDay__c = dateToUpdate;
            accListToUpdate.add(accObj);
        }

        update accListToUpdate;
    }    

}
```

In the above code, there is very high chance that `AccountUtility.setAccountStatus` and `AccountUtility.setBillCycleDay` might update same Account records twice.

Is there a better design pattern for these kind of situations?

I am looking for suggestions that doesn't involve combining the logic inside the methods `AccountUtility.setAccountStatus` and `AccountUtility.setBillCycleDay` into one method and just call that method, assuming it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the Unit of Work design pattern. You manage a list of Sobject and you add elements during the execution of your logic. At the end you perform DML once. This pattern is described by Martin Fowler and have been implement ed in a public repository by Financial Force. Please see this link [Learn Unit of Work Principles](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles)